# Not Allowed Access for all modeul (Document model: ir.filters)

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

[image: Show image here]

I got an error on my Odoo like on the picture, I've checked the user already has access to the user group. It's very thankful if you can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I need more information but whenever you parform the action you are doing a security record rule is trggered, you can try the hard mode, go to security record rules and disable one rule and try and re enable after.

Answer (score 0):

I add this setting (see on the picture) on the user's group I want to give access and it's solved. Apparently it's because the user does not have access to Object ir.filters which most of my modules use this.

[image: Show Image]